# Adjunction of Functors command (tikzcd)

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to create a command for adjunctions of this type:

[image]

I'm trying to use tikzcd but I'm having problems. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\cat{Top}/X = \cat{Bund}\,X \arrow[r,shift left=.5ex,"\Gamma"]
&
\cat{Sets}^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{\op}} \arrow[l,shift left=.5ex,"\Lambda"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having problems with the name of the arrows. 

It says:
Latex Error: ./Haces .tex:253 Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.

If I change the language from spanish to english everything works fine.

Comment: @Abellan Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to your document preamble and try again, please.